# Why is my count++ resetting in my run() method inside the Thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, networking

Every time a connection is made from the client to the server, the client sends a string message "11" to the server, and when the Server receives the string message "11" it operates count++. Then there has been two connections made, which should make count = 2 from count++ operating twice, but when the client connects, I checked it and the client sends the string message "11" correctly to the server, but the count stays as 1 and never enters the if(count == 2) block. Been testing and looking for hours but can't seem to locate the problem. Please help! Thank you

Client's snippet code:

```
Socket s = new Socket(hostname, port); // Plug in the socket to connect to the server
pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()); //Instance of sending it out
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

public void run() { //Deal with reading from server and print them out

    try {
        pw.println("11"); //Sends the message when connection is made to the server
        pw.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{

           while(true){ 

                 String line = br.readLine(); //Read in the message from server

                 if(line.equals("12")){ //When finally receives the string message "12" from   server

                     button.setBackground(Color.white);
                     button.addActionListener(sl);

                 }

                 int update = Integer.parseInt(line);

                 if(update < 10){
                     current-= update;
                 }
     }

    } catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("ioe in ChatClient.run: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Server thread's snippet code:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

public void run(){
    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        while(true){
            String line = br.readLine(); //blocking //Keep reading in messages

            if(line.equals("11")){ //Tested it out and does receive "11" whenever a client connects and prints out "11" 
                count++; //But the problem is count stays as 1 every time it connects and never becomes 2
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(count);
            }

            if(count == 2){ //Never able to reach inside this block of code
                pw.println("12");
                pw.flush();
                count++;
            }
        }

    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("ioe in ChatTHread: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Edit - Server Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Server {

private int count = 0;
private Vector<FFThread> ctVector = new Vector<FFThread>(); //Parametrized

public Server(int port){

    try{

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port); //Server socket to connect to the port

        while(true){

            Socket s = ss.accept();  // Listens for a connection to be made to this "s" socket and accepts it.


            FFThread ct = new FFThread(s, this); //Get new socket access thread
            ctVector.add(ct); //Appends the specified element "ct" to the end of this Vector.
            ct.start(); 
        }

    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("ioe in ChatServer: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}

public int counter(){
    this.count = 0;
    count++;
    return count;
}

public void sendMessage(String message, FFThread ct){
    for(FFThread c : ctVector ){
        if(!c.equals(ct)){ //Two different clients
            c.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

public void removeThread(FFThread ct){
    ctVector.remove(ct);
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What port? ");
    int port = scan.nextInt();
    new Server(port);
}
```

}

Edit - Server's thread class:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FFThread extends Thread {

private Socket s;
private Server cs;
private PrintWriter pw;
private int count = 0;
boolean ready = false;

public FFThread(Socket s, Server cs){

    this.s = s;
    this.cs = cs;

    try{

        this.pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()); //Set up to send messages to clients

    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("ioe in ChatThread constructor: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if the length of the variable `line` is 2, because the comparison could always false and therefore does not increase `count`. For example: "11 " is not equal to "11".

Comment: Try adding "else" blocks and see if your assumptions are correct.   Using an IDE to debug will be useful as well.

Comment: @JoseLuis That isn't seem to be the problem, because I tested it out with System.out.println(line) and System.out.println(count), and they were printed out with line being string "11" but the count always remained 1, proving that they were able to enter the if block.

Comment: @Jayan Could you please elaborate on what you mean down below in as an answer?

Comment: Can you show more server code? The declaration and initialization of `count` would be helpful.

Comment: Exactly. If `count` is initialized with 0 then it will never reach 2, since the client sends "11" only once, according to the code you showed.

Comment: @Eran The initialization is int count = 0;

Comment: @Lolo No, because the client code will be ran twice, which are two clients. The print statement does run twice, but the only problem is that for some reason the count isn't updating.

Comment: Do you have a single thread in your server, or a different thread for each client? You might be having synchronization issues. Is `count` declared as `volatile`?

Comment: @Eran No there is one Client class which is a thread, and I run it twice to connect twice to the Server to create two clients. Nope, it just a private int count = 0;

Comment: How is the Server thread created? Can you show the code that starts the Server thread?

Comment: @Eran edited. Posted my whole Server class as well with the thread class

Comment: Are you saying that you execute the run() method twice for the same client instance, or that you run the client Java application twice? In the second case, this will create two distinct FFThread instances in the server (because 2 socket connections are created), where each FFThread's count never reaches 2.

Comment: @Lolo it's the second case. Then how could I make both of them reach 2 eventually?

Comment: In this case, you need to do `pw.println("11"); pw.flush()` twice in the run() method. However, make sure that you indeed receive "11" twice instead of "1111" once, as I'm not sure the flush() guarantees that you will receive separate strings on the server side. If that happens, then you'll need to change your protocol, for example by adding a delimiter at the end or start of each message, or by using fixed-sized strings for all your messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your Server class starts a new thread (instance of `FFThread`) for each incoming connection. Your `run` method of `FFThread` does `count++`, but it must be doing it on a local variable, since it's not accessing the `count` variable in the Server class. Therefore, each thread increments its own `count` from `0` to `1`, and it never reaches two.

Your `run` method should increment (and test) the `count` variable of the Server instance in order for that count to reach 2. You'll have to increment it in a thread safe manner (i.e. with a synchronized method).

I believe adding the following to your Server class would work :

```
private volatile int count = 0;
...
public synchronized void incCount()
{
    count++;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return count;
}
```

Then, in your `FFThread` class, use `this.cs.getCount()` and `this.cs.incCount()` to read and increment the count.

Comment: do you mind showing? I am so lost... What would be the most convenient way to do it?

Comment: It worked for the second Client that started, but for the first it didn't. I am guessing the first still holds count as 1 but as soon as the count reaches 2 by the second client, should the server have sent the message of string "12" to both clients?

Comment: @OM No, since each server thread sends the message to a single client. The first thread, servicing the first client, didn't send "12", since count wasn't two when it was evaluated. If the first client will send additional input to the server, the server thread's `String line = br.readLine()` call would stop blocking, and the code that checks count and sends "12" will be reached again.

Comment: use either `volatile` or `synchronized` but not both at the same time, as it brings nothing apart from slower code. `volatile` is mostly useful if you only do atomic get() and set() operations, in which case you don't need to use `synchronized`. Since incrementing is not atomic - it's a get() + a set() - volatile is not applicable as is. See the [JLS section 8.3.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4), and also the [AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.html) Javadoc

Comment: @Eran Then how should I get it to send the message to the first client as well when the string reaches "12"?

Comment: @Lolo I wasn't sure if getCount() would be guaranteed to get the current value of `count` if it was changed by the other thread. That's why I added `volatile`. I may have been wrong.

Comment: @Eran Would there be such a way to send the message to the first client as well when the string reaches "12"??

Comment: @OM You might use `setSoTimeout` to set your socket's timeout, so that your readLine method doesn't block when there is no input. In case of no input, you'll get a TimeoutException, and if you catch it, your code would proceed to test the count and send the message.

Comment: @Eran I just attempted but don't seem to work... maybe I am doing something wrong? Do you mind showing?